# Importing the tabular format text file in excel not aligned properly

Tags: python, excel, csv, tabular

I have crated a table format text file  using python **tabulate 0.7.7** module and the result look as expected.

***Result:***
report.txt

```
Name   server1  server 2
adams    Y         N
machine  N         Y
```

When I copy paste the text the proper looking format get scrambled.

> My goal is to import it in excel sheet. When importing in ubuntu
>   LibreOffice Calc the result is as below

[image]

They are not separate by columns all are in a single row.
What delimiters does the tabulate  uses is it because of the tabulate problem of the tabulate module

How can I solve this issue now.I don't want to convert the text file into csv again but want it to be easily importable in excel in a csv formating

Comment: check the image avove its scrambled and coming in single row not separated  with column as in csv file .Doesnot look like csv format

Comment: It's a delimiter problem of tabulate module. I have to some extend succeeded to generate  column by selecting the separate options as *space* but the problem with this is that if the value say has name separated with space than it will take it as separate parameter. Adams Eve will be separated as two different value

Comment: Why are you using `tabulate`? If you want a CSV, then use the `csv` module. If you want an Excel workbook, then use XlsxWriter. Or use `pandas`.

Comment: I want data in text tabular format such that it can also be imported as csv easily. I am just trying not to use external library as much as possible. I succeeded and didn't  even use tabulate , THANKS